# LibGDX - rendering particles in the wrong position after resize

Tags: java, libgdx

Currently I have 2 screens, a main menu and a battle screen. When i move directly from the main menu screen to the battle screen without resizing, everything works normally, but when i resize my main menu and then move to my battlescreen, the particles (and only the particles) get rendered incorrectly.

I have tried :

-updating the viewport in the show method of the battlescreen

-setting the projectionmatrix of the spritebatch to the camera's combined of either the mapcamera or the unitcamera.

-applying every viewport (there are 3) before rendering.

***THE MAIN MENU SCEEN***

https://snag.gy/cJCnRt.jpg

```
private Stage _stage;

public MainMenuScreen(Object... params){
    _stage = new Stage();
    backgroundbatch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
     backgroundbatch.begin();
     backgroundbatch.draw(_currentFrame, 0, 0,_stage.getViewport().getWorldWidth(),_stage.getViewport().getWorldHeight()); // Draw current frame at (0, 0)
     backgroundbatch.end();

    _stage.act(delta);
    _stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    _stage.getViewport().setScreenSize(width, height);
    //_stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

***THE BATTLESCREEN CLASS***

```
private void initializeHUD() {
    _hudCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    _hudCamera.setToOrtho(false, VIEWPORT.physicalWidth, VIEWPORT.physicalHeight);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    _camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    _camera.setToOrtho(false, map.getMapWidth(), map.getMapHeight());

    _mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(_mapMgr.getCurrentTiledMap(), Map.UNIT_SCALE);
    _mapRenderer.setView(_camera);

    spritebatch = new SpriteBatch();
    map.makeSpawnParticles();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    _camera.update();
    _hudCamera.update();

    //draw particles
    ParticleMaker.drawAllActiveParticles(spritebatch, delta);

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    Player.getInstance().getEntityStage().getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    _playerBattleHUD.resize(width, height);
    map.getTiledMapStage().getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```

***PARTICLE MANAGER CLASS***

```
public static void drawAllActiveParticles(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, float delta) {
    for (ArrayList<Particle> particleTypeList : allParticles.values()) {
        spriteBatch.begin();
        for(Particle particle : particleTypeList) {
            if(particle.isActive()) {
                particle.update(delta);
                particle.draw(spriteBatch,delta);
            }

            if (particle.isComplete()) {
                particle.delete();
                //particles.remove(particle);
            }
        }
        spriteBatch.end();
    }
}
```

***PARTICLE CLASS***

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, float delta) {
    Gdx.app.debug("Particle : ", "spritebatch position = " + spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().getScaleX() + " , " + spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().getScaleY() + ")"); 
    particleEffect.draw(spriteBatch, delta);
}
```

expected results : 
https://snag.gy/q2txr5.jpg  (particles are the yellow dots)

results (after resizing the main screen):
https://snag.gy/g81ZJ7.jpg

noteworthy : after resizing, the spritebatch projectionmatrix shows a different value in comparison to not having resized the main menu.

Comment: Where are you applying the camera's projection matrix to the sprite batch, or is that what you're missing?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have tried using both of the cameras I have available, but both those options did not work. If I try to use the tiled map camera then no particles appear. If I use the ui camera then the same issue remains.

Comment: Do you have multiple stages in your game? If you do and they have different viewports, you need to call viewport.apply() before drawing each of those respective stages. If your particles are drawn as part of the same world as your tiles, it wouldn't make sense to use any other camera for them.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "resizing" your main menu?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I do have multiple stages , I tried doing viewport.apply() before every stage gets rendered. With no effect.

The thing is that resizing correctly repositions all the particles, only if the window gets resized at the main menu, and then swaps to the battle screen, the particles are not positioned corrdctly

Resizing the main menu means making the initial main menu screen bigger by dragging the corner. Then the user presses "new game" and then the battlescreen appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with similar issues, I fixed my problem by using my tiledmaprenderer's batch to render my particles.